# Как лучше рассчитать экспоненциальное скользящее среднее?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Как лучше рассчитать экспоненциальное скользящее среднее?

Comment: Можно еще задать в гугл вопрос в "какие у питона есть библиотеки для работы с финансами или анализа временных рядов", возможно это автоматом поможет решить вам еще десяток следующих вопросов.

Comment: related: [calculate exponential moving average in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/488670/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по вашим предыдущим вопросам, вы работаете с Pandas DataFrame.

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.ewm(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  4.0

>>> df.ewm(com=0.5).mean()
          B
0  0.000000
1  0.750000
2  1.615385
3  1.615385
4  3.670213
```